# É possivel executar este código de 10 em 10 segundos?

Tags: node.js, ip, ping

Eu tenho este bloco de código que diz se os meus ip's estão OK ou NOK eu pretendo executar o código de 10 em 10 segundos de forma a não estar sempre a executar na linha de comandos, existe alguma maneira de fazer isso? Já vi alguns métodos chamados setInterval e setTimeout mas não sei se é isso.

```
const dotenev = require('dotenv');
dotenev.config();
const ping = require('ping');

const hosts = JSON.parse(process.env.SERVERS_TO_MONITORIZE);

hosts.forEach(function (host) {
    ping.sys.probe(host.ip, function (isAlive) {  
        if (isAlive) {
            host.status = 'OK';
            console.log(host.name + ' ' + host.ip + ' ' + host.status);
        } else {
            host.status = 'NOK';
            console.log(host.name + ' ' + host.ip + ' ' + host.status);
        }
       return host.status;
    });
});

module.exports = hosts;
```

Comment: Por que tem que fazer a verificação de disponibilidade a cada 10s? Não seria mais simples através de um [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) fazer essa verificação apenas quando alguma parte do programa consultasse a propriedade `status` de um determinado host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é utilizando a lib `node-cron`.

Para isso primeiramente faça a instalação da lib `node-cron` utilizando o comando:

```
npm install node-cron
```

Depois basta importar esta lib, e criar uma expressão no padrão de um [`cronjob`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab)

> *Cronjob*: O utilitário de linha de comando cron, também conhecido como cron job, é um agendador de tarefas em sistemas operacionais do tipo Unix. Os usuários que configuram e mantêm ambientes de software usam o cron para agendar trabalhos para serem executados periodicamente em horários, datas ou intervalos fixos.

Segue um exemplo de utilização:

```
const cron = require("node-cron");

cron.schedule("*/6 * * * * *", () => console.log("Executando a tarefa a cada 10 segundos"));
```

Após montar o script, supondo que o nome dado ao arquivo seja `tarefa.js` e que contenha o conteúdo acima, para executar a cada 10s basta executar utilizando o tempo de execução do nodejs com o comando:

```
node tarefa.js
```

Ao fazer isso verá que a mensagem `Executando a tarefa a cada 10 segundos` será exibida em tela a cada 10s.

---

Para realizar tarefas agendadas baseadas em tempo. Você vai precisar de utilizar uma expressão no padrão de cronjob. (Um padrão do Unix).

Além da utilização do `node-cron`, uma solução baseada na instalação de bibliotecas externas, se tiver utilizando um sistema operacional baseado em Unix, pode fazer utilização do serviço cronjob do Unix.

## Sintaxe do cron

Esta é uma referência rápida à sintaxe do cron e também mostra as opções suportadas pelo node-cron.

```
  ┌────────────── segundos (opcional)
  │ ┌──────────── minuto
  │ │ ┌────────── hora
  │ │ │ ┌──────── dia do mês
  │ │ │ │ ┌────── mês
  │ │ │ │ │ ┌──── dia da semana
  │ │ │ │ │ │
  │ │ │ │ │ │
  * * * * * *
```

Ou pode utilizar alguma ferramenta para ajudar a montar a expressão do cronjob.

Comment: De facto era isso que queria, mas se eu alterar algum ip continua a dar OK, ou seja, o código que é repetido é sempre o mesmo, não atualiza de acordo com os dados fornecidos durante a execução

Comment: Deixa eu vê se entendi. Você quer modificar os valores que estão no arquivo `.env` e quer que estas mudanças sejam refletidas no código. É isso? @FranciscoMarques

Comment: sim exatamente isso, é possivel?

Comment: Se quer este comportamento, deve colocar a chamada `dotenev.config();` dentro do método a ser chamado no intervalo de tempo.

Comment: Ok muito obrigado pela ajuda!!

Comment: @FranciscoMarques caso a resposta tenha lhe atendido, não esqueça de marcar o V ao lado da mesma para que outras pessoas identifiquem o que resolveu o seu problema