# Monitoramento IP PYTHON

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ip, monitoramento

Estou criando um codigo no python para monitorar um link internet, nao estou sabendo como fazer para realizar o ping constante e quando nao responder enviar uma mensagem para o telegram inforando que o link esta off. sou iniciante no python

Comment: informando* que o link esta off.

Comment: Cara, seguinte, essa tua pergunta parece com outra que tem [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/550244/103217). Pode utilizar a pergunta e resposta contida nela.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [É possivel executar este código de 10 em 10 segundos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/550244/%c3%89-possivel-executar-este-c%c3%b3digo-de-10-em-10-segundos)

Answer (score 1):

```py
import os

def myping(host):
    response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + host)
    
    if response == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
        
print(myping("8.8.8.8"))
```